# Spark RDD.map use within a spark dataframe withColumn method

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code:

```
from pyspark import *;
from pyspark.sql import *;
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType
import math;

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').getOrCreate();


schema = StructType([
    StructField("INDEX", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("SYMBOL", StringType(), True),
    StructField("DATETIMETS", StringType(), True),
    StructField("PRICE", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("SIZE", IntegerType(), True),
])

df = spark\
    .createDataFrame(
        data=[(0,'A','2002-12-02 9:30:20',19.75,30200),
             (1,'A','2002-12-02 9:31:20',19.75,30200),             
             (8,'A','2004-12-02 10:36:20',1.0,30200),
             (9,'A','2006-12-02 22:41:20',20.0,30200),
             (10,'A','2006-12-02 22:42:20',40.0,30200)],
        schema=schema);
```

I then do some computations without using spark.
This works fine.

```
def without_spark(price):    
    first_summation = sum(map(lambda n: math.sqrt(price), range(1,10)));
    return first_summation;

u_without_spark = udf(without_spark, DoubleType())

df.withColumn("NEW_COL", u_without_spark('PRICE')).show()
```

[image: No Spark Output]

The following code that uses rdd parallelization however does not.

```
def with_spark(price):    
    rdd = sc.parallelize(1, 10)
    first_summation = rdd.map(lambda n: math.sqrt(price));
    return first_summation.sum();

u_with_spark = udf(with_spark, DoubleType())

df.withColumn("NEW_COL", u_with_spark('PRICE')).show()
```

[image: Spark Error]

Is what I am trying to do not possible?
Is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call any RDD methods from within a UDF.

When you create a UDF, it runs on the workers. RDD or dataframe operations can only run on the driver and therefore are not allowed in the UDF.

It seems as if your goal is to do a UDAF (User Defined Aggregate Method). This cannot be done from pyspark. You have two options for this. Either use collect_list and then do a UDF on the resulting array or write the UDAF in scala and wrap it for pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

> > I then do some computations without using spark

When you created `dataframe`, you used *SparkSession*, so you already are using *spark*. `udf` and `withColumn` are *spark dataframe*'s apis which are used to transform `dataframe`.

`Dataframes` are distributed in nature i.e. all the transformations on `dataframes` are done in worker nodes. So the `udf` by using `withColumn` `transformation` are all done on worker nodes. You created `sparkContext` (`sc`) in the driver node which cannot be used in transformations.

> > Is what I am trying to do not possible? Is there a faster way to do this?

Your second implementation is wrong as you are trying to access `sparkContext` from within transformation.

Your first method seems to be working fine and is already using spark. So I guess you don't need to look for alternatives.

Comment: if the answer is helpful please consider accepting it